# How can I show custom 404 pages for mulitple domains under one hosting account?

Tags: php

I'm using a GoDaddy hosting account to host multiple domains. How can I show a custom 404 for each of these domains?

All of the non-primary domains are in folders in the root of the primary domain.

I tried setting the custom domain page in the hosting account options for the primary domain to a 404.php that then redirected errors on the non-primary domains to their own respective 404.html.

It looked like this:

```
<?php

$ref = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if(strpos($ref, "example2.com"))
{
header( 'Location: http://example2.com/errorpage.html' ) ;
}
elseif(strpos($ref, "example3.com"))
{
header( 'Location: http://example3.com/errorpage.html' ) ;
}
else
{
header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/error/' ) ;
}
?>
```

No dice. Has anyone had success with this technique?

Answer (score 2):

After spending an hour or so researching this I decided to keep it simple.

First upload a customized `/error.html` page.
Then simply upload an `.htaccess` file for each hosted domain that says:

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
```

It should take less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate `.htaccess` file in each folder with it's own set of rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://otherdomain.com/404.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually running into the same exact problem. I am currently hosting 5 domains in my deluxe hosting account. 
This is how I easily solved the issue...

**STEP1:** 
Set your Godaddy 404 domain page to a custom url (http://www.yourwebsitename/notfound.php). Create this page (notfound.php) in your root directory (Unfortunately Godaddy's custom 404 redirect only works in the root).

**STEP 2.** 
On the landing page of the domain the customer visits, create a COOKIE that includes the full path to the website.

```
<?php 
$redirectionname = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; // GETS URL PATH OF THE CURRENT DOMAIN BEING VIEWED (WWW.YOURSITENAME.COM).

setcookie("RedirectSite",'',time()-3200); // KILLS THE COOKIE IF IT ALREADY EXISTS AND STARTS FRESH.
setcookie("RedirectSite",$redirectionname); // SETS THE COOKIE TO DOMAIN URL "WWW.YOURSITENAME.COM".

// THIS WILL CREATE THE COOKIE NAME "RedirectSite" WITH THE VALUE OF "WWW.YOURSITENAME.COM".
?>
```

**STEP 3:** 
Now that we have the customer's browser remembering a cookie with the website's name, we have to create a way for the 404 landing page to recognize this...

```
<?php

// REDIRECT CUSTOMER TO CUSTOMER 404 WITHIN SPECIFIC SITE (SUBDOMAIN).

if(isset($_COOKIE['RedirectSite'])) //CHECKS TO SEE IF THE URL TO THE SITE IS SET AS A COOKIE
{
    $RedirectSite =  "http://";  // THE SITE COOKIE DOES NOT HAVE THIS PREFIX, SO YOU MUST APPEND IT FOR REDIRECT TO WORK.
    $RedirectSite .= $_COOKIE['RedirectSite'];  // THIS IS YOUR SITE STORED IN A COOKIE (ie: www.yoursitename.com)
    $RedirectSite .= "/oops.php?error=1&type=404"; // THIS IS THE PATH TO YOUR CUSTOMER 404 PG. NOTE: MUST INCLUDE "/" BEFORE PG.

    echo "redirecting...";  // IF THE USER'S BROWSER IS SLOW, IT LET'S THEM KNOW THEY ARE BEING REDIRECTED. THIS SHOULD NOT SHOW NORMALLY.

header("Location: ".$RedirectSite.""); // REDIRECT BROWSER TO CUSTOM 404 URL PG.

exit(); // KILLS ALL CODING AFTER THIS SCRIPT

}else{

    echo "Please press BACK"; // RESPONSE BACK IF THE COOKIE IS NOT SET. THE USER MUST MANUALLY GO BACK.
}


?>
```

**STEP 4:** 
Create your custom 404 pg within the directory you want it to show  (oops.php). Use PHP so you can attach variables to the url for $_GET purposes.

```
<?php
// "http://yoursitename.com/oops.php?error=1&type=404"

$response= $_GET['error']; // GETS THE VARIABLE "error" FROM THE URL.

if($response == '1') // CHECKS TO SEE IF SERVER GAVE USER AN ERROR. "1" MEANS YES.
{
    echo "There was an error opening this page. See below..."; // REDIRECTED BY AN ERROR
}else{
    echo "Everything is great! No error to report. Have a great day! :)"; // THE USER VISITED THE 404 PAGE WITHOUT BEING REDIRECTED BY AN ERROR. 
    exit();
    die();
}

?>

<h1>404!</h1>
<h2>Page does not exist...</h2>
```

**STEP 5:** 
YOU ARE DONE! Enjoy your new custom 404 page for each domain in your hosting plan! 
**STEP 6:** 
Create beautiful designs.
**STEP 7:** 
Ready?... Set... CODE!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I have around 20 domains hosted on [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) deluxe account I am using the following script and its working fine for me:

```
<?php
  $hostName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $hostSlices = explode(".",$hostName);

  if ($hostSlices[0]=="www") {
    array_shift($hostSlices);
  }

  $domain = join(".",$hostSlices);

  if ($domain == "domain1.com") {
    header('Location: http://domain1.com/404');
    exit();
  } elseif($domain == "domain2.com") {
    header('Location: http://domain2.com/404/');
    exit();
  } elseif($domain == "domain3.com") {
    header('Location: http://domain3.com/404/');
    exit();
  } else {
    exit();
  }
?>
```